# Amazon EC2 Instance - only accepting single connections?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having a lot of trouble with an EC2 instance and I can't figure out what's going on.  We're using it as a web server and it seems to work fine for single connection stuff - loading a simple page, RDP connection, ping etc.  But as soon as a single client computer has more than one connection active with the server (a good example is if I try to browse the web site while I'm also logged into the server via RDP) the whole connection becomes incredibly unstable.

The biggest most annoying consequence of this is that the ASP.NET site that we're running consistently fails to load some pages since those pages use more than one connection.  This wasn't a problem up until a few days ago when we were forced to migrate to different hardware because our hardware was apparently being retired by Amazon.  Ever since then it's been tricky like this.  Is it possible that there's a kink in Amazon's network and that it could potentially be resolved by stopping and starting the instance (and thus getting a different server?)

Comment: You could stop/restart. Being Windows I do have to wonder if there isn't a license issue involved.

Comment: @datasage a license issue?  License for what exactly?

Comment: Windows uses requires client access licenses for certain uses or requires you do use a server edition over desktop edition if you want IIS to allow more than 10 connections. What size instance are you using? when you had to move to new hardware, did you just stop/start?

Comment: We're using Server 2012 with IIS 8.0.  The instance size is m1.medium. I should also mention that the server isn't straining at all during these timeouts, it definitely appears to be a network issue rather than an issue within the instance itself.  And yeah, to move to the new hardware we just stopped and then started the instance, which were the instructions provided in the email we received about the retirement.

Comment: @datasage just want to say thanks for trying to help out with this one, I appreciate your time - I've answered the question myself below so you can see what the eventual solution was.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was an underlying issue on Amazon's end.  They investigated the issue and found a problem that they're correcting.  I hope I haven't wasted too much StackOverflow brainpower with this dead-end of a question!